# Why are complicated elements like XMLNS needed in the SVG-tag?

Tags: svg

I'm creating an SVG. The SVG-tag looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="800">
```

If I replace that with a simple `<svg width="800" height="800">` tag, the document is blank. In Chrome, it works if I take away the upper tag but not the XMLNS. In IE11, as soon as I take away anything (the DOCTYPE, the XMLNS, the PUBLIC...) the document is blank. Why do I need such complicated elements?

Comment: In what context are you using this SVG?  In a browser?

Comment: Yes, I don't see in what other context you can use SVG, but that may be because I'm a beginner.

Comment: Did you really mean `<!DOCTYPE svg width="800" height="800">` or is that a typo?  You have mixed a combination of the doctype and the root SVG tag.  Which won't work.

Comment: No. I meant that the file that works has `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC ...><svg xmlns="..." width="800" height="800">` and the way I want it to be is simply `<svg width="800" height="800">`. I edited this mistake to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG files are XML files. As such, when they are standalone files, they need some sort of pre-amble so that whatever parsing it knows what to do.  So standalone SVG files need to at least have the xmlns attribute.  The browser requires that.  However, the DocType is not necessary unless you want to do proper XML validation.

When an SVG is inlined in the body of an HTML page, you don't need either.  The HTML parser knows about SVG content and knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't needed. The trick is you need to use a mime type of text/html rather than image/svg+xml (or any other XML mime type).

```html
<!doctype html>
<svg width="500" height="350">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

If you use an XML mime type then XML supports namespaces and you have to define them hence the need for the xmlns attributes to distinguish whether `<a>` is an html `<a>` with a src attribute or an SVG `<a>` element with an xlink:href attribute. HTML just magically guesses at that.

Comment: It certainly does on Firefox, Chrome, IE9+. As I said in the answer though you **must** serve it with a text/html mime type.